# Complement of unsigned int

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I recently came across the following piece of code:

```
unsigned short int a = 0xffff;
~a;
printf("%x", a);
```

Its output is:

```
0xffff
```

From what I have learnt, `~a` should flip all the bits of a giving the following:

```
0x0000
```

So, why is the output `0xffff`?

Comment: Tip: Always compile with full warnings, and the compiler will warn you.

Comment: This is not a "simple typographical error", nor was this "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers". Vote to reopen.

Comment: Although the question has been resolved, I don't see how it is off-topic or how it is "unlikely to help future readers". Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to assign the result back to a. Just like

```
int a = 3; 
a + 2; 
printf ("%d\n", a);
```

will print 3 and not 5.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not assigning it to `a`, value is just discarded, try

```
a = ~a;
```

Comment: @ScottyBauer Why would it be?

Answer (score 0):

As most other operators, ~ does not modify the variable in-place, but "returns" the modified value as its result. Think about the unary minus: if you want to change sign to a variable you don't do

```
-a;
```

but

```
a=-a;
```

The same holds for the bitwise not operator; to get the result you expect do:

```
a=~a;
```